# How to send XML file from smart device to PC in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, readfile

I'm developing a web application for a handheld RFID reader (windows CE),
and I'm trying to send an XML file from the RFID reader to a laptop throgh wireless network or GPRS. The code works properly with "windows form application" on MS visual studio, but when I try to use it with "smart device application" it doesn't work... an error appears for the "ReadAllBytes" method:

`System.IO.File dose not contain a definition for ReadAllBytes`

Please help me to handle this error.
Thanks.

---

The code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{

string IpAddressString = "10.1.1.104";

IPEndPoint ipEnd_client = new
IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddressString), 5656);

Socket clientSock_client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

string fileName = "student.XML";
string filePath =@"My Device\";

fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
{

filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);

fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
}

byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
if (fileNameByte.Length > 5000 * 1024)
{
curMsg_client = "File size is more than 5Mb,
please try with small file.";
MessageBox.Show("File size is more than 5Mb,
please try with small file.");
return;
}

MessageBox.Show("Buffering ...");

string fullPath = filePath + fileName;
byte[] fileData =File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);

byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length +
fileData.Length];

//byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length];

byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);

fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

MessageBox.Show("Connection to server ...");
clientSock_client.Connect(ipEnd_client);

MessageBox.Show("File sending...");

clientSock_client.Send(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, 0);

MessageBox.Show("Disconnecting...");
clientSock_client.Close();

MessageBox.Show ("File [" + fullPath + "] transferred.");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
if (ex.Message == "No connection could be made
because the target machine actively refused it")
{

MessageBox.Show ("File Sending fail. Because
server not running.");
}
else
{

MessageBox.Show ("File Sending fail." +
ex.Message.ToString());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because, as the error states, ReadAllBytes doesn't exist in the Compact Framework.  You have to use an overload of Read to get the data.

Something along these lines:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    var fileData = new byte[reader.Length];
    reader.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
}
```

Comment: When I tried to implement this, and after i run it an error message said:     `could not find a part of the path` ..   can you tell me how to embed it in the code??

Comment: Probably because you have invalid paths.  Why are you replacing backslashes (\\) with forward slashes (/)?  Windows uses the backslash (\\) for paths.

Comment: Windows CE also doesn't support relative paths, so "MyDevice\student.xml" is invalid.  It probably should be "\MyDevice\student.xml"